# How to get value of input field ? Vue unit-test Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, vuejs2, jestjs, vuetify.js

I am trying test the value of an Iput field but somehow the .text() always returns nothing and I don't understand why or how could I get the value of the input element

**file.spec.ts**

```
const textFieldPhone = wrapper.find('[data-cy="text-field-telephone"');
await textFieldPhone.setValue('11111');

expect(wrapper.vm.$data.phoneNumber).toBe('11111'); // pass
expect(textFieldPhone.text()).toBe('11111'); // error
```

> ```
> Error: expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality
>
> Expected: "11111"
> Received: ""
> ```

```
console.log(textField.html())

=> <input data-cy="text-field-telephone" id="input-32" type="text"/>
```

How can I get the value of the element ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this: `expect(textFieldPhone.element.value).toBe('11111')`

Comment: I got this error: TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Element'.

Comment: I had to cast the type for typescript:

Comment: const inputPhone = textFieldPhone.element as HTMLInputElement;

Comment: expect(inputPhone.value).toBe('11111');